# set cookie throw curl request

Tags: php, curl

I want to set cookie throw curl request. I used this code but the requested URL return `You must enable Javascript and accept cookies.` what Im doing wrong here?

`cookie.txt` file is 0644 permission

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not your code, it's that the page you're trying to access works only by executing javascript. `CURL` doesn't support that, it just downloads the HTML code of the page, but doesn't execute any javascript.

If you're in the need of retrieving information from a website that needs to execute javascript, you need to rely on solutions that provide headless browsers, like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)